# ¿Cómo evitar que un RecyclerView se desplace cuando añado elementos?

Tags: android, android-studio, recyclerview

Estoy tratando de poblar un RecyclerView con un GridLayoutManager. En mi archivo XML tengo arriba del RecyclerView un título y una descripción pero cuando inició la actividad no se muestra el título porque el contenido que añadí al RecyclerView lo desplazó hacia abajo, he intentado de todo para evitar que esto no pase y la única solución que he encontrado es retrasando los datos que le mando al adapter y luego hacer un notifyDataSetChange();

No sé porqué pasa eso creo que retrasar a propósito los datos es una mala práctica, si alguien sabe porque pasa esto le agradecería que me dijera el porqué.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    tools:context=".CategoryRestaurantActivity">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView android:id="@+id/ft_tittle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Titulo"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/ft_description"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ft_tittle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:text="Descripcion"
                android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rc_filter_restaurant"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ft_description"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
        </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Java**

```
    RecyclerView recyclerFilter = findViewById(R.id.rc_filter_restaurant);

    recyclerFilter.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(CategoryRestaurantActivity.this, 2));
    recyclerFilter.setHasFixedSize(true);
    adapter = new FilterRestaurantAdapter(CategoryRestaurantActivity.this, filters);
    recyclerFilter.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerFilter.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    /* retaso para evitar el scroll del recycler*/ 
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setFilter();
        }
    },2000);
}

private void setFilter(){
    filters = new ArrayList<>();
    filters.add(new Filters("Comida Rápida", R.drawable.ft_comida_rapida));
    filters.add(new Filters("Buffet", R.drawable.ft_comida_buffet));
    filters.add(new Filters("Comida China",R.drawable.ft_comida_china));
    filters.add(new Filters("Comida Mexicana",R.drawable.ft_comida_mexicana));
    filters.add(new Filters("Comida Saludable",R.drawable.ft_comida_saludable));
    filters.add(new Filters("Pizzerias",R.drawable.ft_pizzerias));
    filters.add(new Filters("Mariscos",R.drawable.ft_mariscos));


    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

[image: El titulo no se muestra si no retaso los datos que le paso al adaptador]

Comment: Hola, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir el código `axml` de tu Layout y en su defecto el código?, asi ayudarías a encontrar una solución a tu problema, ya que la pregunta es algo ambigüa, si no hay código para identificar el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que de parent tienes un `ScrollView`. Por ende, al hacer el tamaño de su hijo (`RelativeLayout`) como `wrap_content` y el RecyclerView también, este crecerá tanto como el `RecyclerView`. El contenido se convertirá en `Scrollable` al exceder el `Height` del `ScrollView`.

### Es realmente el ScrollView necesario en este escenario?

Aparentemente no. Por lo que bastaría tener un hijo, donde solo el `RecyclerView` sea `Scrollable`, si eso es lo que quieres lograr. Ahora bien, dado que quieres tener hijos de manera "Lineal", es decir, uno debajo del otro. El padre recomendado es un `LinearLayout`, ya que no necesitas fijar ni superponer. Tu solucion entonces seria la siguiente.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".CategoryRestaurantActivity">

      <TextView android:id="@+id/ft_tittle"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
         android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
         android:text="Titulo"
         android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
         android:textSize="22sp"
         android:textStyle="bold" />

      <TextView android:id="@+id/ft_description"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
         android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
         android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
         android:text="Descripcion"
         android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"
         android:textSize="14sp"
         android:textStyle="normal" />

      <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
         android:id="@+id/rc_filter_restaurant"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ¡Funciona, gracias! 

Comment: Una pregunta más ¿Cómo haría en el caso de que quisiera que el título y la descripción tuvieran scroll para que no se queden fijo mientras muevo el RecyclerView? 

Comment: @Sergio94 cargando diferentes vistas dentro del recyclerview

Comment:  como haría algo así?